# Calculation returns NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a page that allows for the multiple upload of images, this requires different name attributes. To achieve this, I'm using JS to add one the variable `i` giving a number.

The below code returns NaN, I'm not too sure why?

```
$('document').ready(function() {
var i = 1;
$('#new-dialogue').click(function() {
    var i = i + 1;
    $('.create-upload').append('<div class="upload"><input type="file" name="image' + i + '"/></div>');
});
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the second `var`.

What your current code is saying, is what when `new-dialogue` is clicked, it should create a variable called `i` and set it to `i+1`... but because `i` hasn't been defined yet in this scope you are doing `undefined + 1`, which is `NaN`.

Removing the second `var` will cause the click function to get the `i` variable from the containing scope, which is what you want it to do. You can then just have `i++` to increment it as needed.

That said, you could just make your life easier by using:

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" />
```

Because on the server side, you will then have an array of uploaded files ;)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
var i = i + 1;
```

Just do

```
i++;
```

You need to increment already declared variable, *not* re-declare it again.

Answer (score 2):

When you redeclared `i` local to the callback, your function got its own local copy of `i` that had yet to receive a value. So `var i = i + 1;` is basically `var i = undefined + 1;`, which evaluates to `NaN`.

Get rid of the `var` to fix this.